# Strange case involving TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously

Tags: c#, async-await, task, taskcompletionsource

```
async void Main()
{
    T0.TT();
}

private class T0
{
    [ThreadStatic] private static int test;

    public static async void TT()
    {
        test = 4;
        var continuation = new System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<int>(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        var th = new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(500); Console.WriteLine(test); test = 3; continuation.TrySetResult(5); test = 7; });
        th.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(await continuation.Task);
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

```
Output:
0
5
3
```

So without the `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` this was written to demonstrate the rest of the `async` method runs on the thread created by `new Thread()`. However with `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` it still somehow finds that specific `[ThreadStatic]` value that is set in the newly created thread (thus can't be a TaskScheduler thread) and cleared as soon as `TrySetResult` returns.

What the hey? How is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be passing `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`, not `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`.

Passing `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` will call the [overload that takes an `object` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCompletionSource_1__ctor_System_Object_), treating it as a "state" object and not as a flag controlling the TCS behavior.